# How to cache and replay the items of a Supplier<Stream<T>>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Regarding a `Supplier<Stream<T>> dataSrc` I would like to cache the `Stream` items for further traversals of the same sequence of elements. In this case, assume that `dataSrc` always produces the same sequence (e.g. getting a `Stream<Integer>` with temperatures in Celsius of March (see example usage bellow)). Thus, option 1) is to first **collect** the `Stream` items, however it will **waste one first traversal to add those items into a collection**:

```
Supplier<Stream<T>> dataSrc = ...
List<T> cache = dataSrc.collect(toList()); // **Additional** traversal to collect items
cache.stream().reduce(…) // 1st traversal
cache.stream().reduce(…) // 2nd traversal
... // Nth  traversals
```

I would like to **avoid the additional traversal** to collect items and the explicit `cache` variable and hide it inside the `Supplier<>` in such a way that on first traversal the items are implicitly cached and on further traversals the items are accessed from that cache. I think this is similar to the idea of the method [cache()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#cache--) of Reactor Project for reactive streams.

Thus, I am outlining an alternative in the following `cache()` method implementation, although it already has two problems (at least): 1) the `onClose` is not called on traversal finish (and I cannot figure out any way of detecting the end of a traversal); 2) If the first traversal never ends then the cache will never be filled.

```
Supplier<Stream<T>> dataSrc = cache(...)
dataSrc.get().reduce(…) // 1st traversal
dataSrc.get().reduce(…) // 2nd traversal
... // Nth  traversals

static <T> Supplier<Stream<T>> cache(Supplier<Stream<T>> dataSrc) {
    final List<T> cache = new ArrayList<>();
    final AtomicBoolean started = new AtomicBoolean();
    final AtomicBoolean isCached = new AtomicBoolean();
    return () -> {
        if(isCached.get()) return cache.stream();
        if(!started.getAndSet(true)) {
            return dataSrc
                .get()
                .peek(cache::add)
                .onClose(() -> isCached.set(true));
        }
        return dataSrc.get();
    };
}
```

### Question:

Is there any better approach to achieve an utility `cache()` function which returns a new `Stream<T>` that **caches items on first `Stream` traversal** (**without** an implicit additional traversal to collect first) and further `Stream` objects are created from that cache?

### Usage Example:

Here I am getting a stream with the temperatures in March from the [World Weather online API](https://developer.worldweatheronline.com/api/historical-weather-api.aspx). To execute it you must include a dependency of [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client) and a valid API key in given URI.

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\n");
boolean [] isEven = {true};
CompletableFuture<Stream<Integer>> temps = asyncHttpClient()
    .prepareGet("http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/past-weather.ashx?q=37.017,-7.933&date=2018-03-01&enddate=2018-03-31&tp=24&format=csv&key=715b185b36034a4c879141841182802")
    .execute()
    .toCompletableFuture()
    .thenApply(Response::getResponseBody)
    .thenApply(pat::splitAsStream)
    .thenApply(str -> str
            .filter(w -> !w.startsWith("#")) // Filter comments
            .skip(1)                         // Skip line: Not Available
            .filter(l -> isEven[0] = !isEven[0]) // Filter Even line
            .map(line -> line.substring(14, 16)) // Extract temperature in celcius
            .map(Integer::parseInt)
    );
```

Note that a `CompletableFuture<Stream<Integer>>` is functionally compliant with a `Supplier<Stream<Integer>>`. Although, the `CompletableFuture` caches the resulting stream it cannot be iterated twice.

**Problem 1**: The following code throws `IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed`

```
out.println(temps.join().distinct().count());
out.println(temps.join().max(Integer::compare)); // throws IllegalStateException
```

**Problem 2**: Collecting it in a `List` will induce a first traversal and thus we will have 3 traversals, instead of 2:

```
CompletableFuture<List<Integer>> list = temps.thenApply(str -> str.collect(toList()));
out.println(list.join().stream().distinct().count()); // 2 traversals
out.println(list.join().stream().distinct().max(Integer::compare));// 1 traversal
```

**Goal**: **Store items in cache on first traversal.** Every time the stream retrieves an item it should store it in an internal cache that will be used on further traversals.

```
Supplier<Stream<Integer>> cache = Cache.of(temps::join);
out.println(temps.get().distinct().count()); // 1 traversal
out.println(temps.get().max(Integer::compare)); // 1 traversal form cache
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how this can be useful at all. If you want a new stream each time, why don't you just ask for one to its source whenever you need it? Why all the cache and flags, if you already have the source?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner notice that a `Supplier<Stream<T>>` is lazy and may not be in-memory. Imagine that data comes from a DB, or Restful API, or anywhere. Every time you got the stream from the supplier you will incur in IO, which you can avoid if you cache the resulting sequence.

Comment: Don't cache the stream, cache the source, then

Comment: Indeed. That is what I am looking for: "_cache the source_". Note that `Supplier<Stream<T>>` variable is called `dataSrc` meaning _data source_, an abstraction over the source.

Comment: @JensHoffmann I think that you should keep your proposal since there is no perfect solution, and all alternatives have advantages and disadvantages. Your proposal is concise and less verbose, which is also very important and can be useful for other programmers looking for other alternatives in this same context.

Comment: Yes, I added it back

Comment: I am still not sure whether this is a well defined problem with the right abstractions. You state that getting the stream via dataSrc is expensive (represented by `Supplier#get`), however you also state that the contained stream might be infinite, lazily evaulated, whereas these evaluations might be expensive too. Also note that according to the [Stream doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html), a `Stream` is _supposed_ to be operate-once and not reused, especially not forked, which is what you are trying to do (you want cached forks).

Comment: So depending on the problem you're trying to solve, I think the solution is to either cache the data src and returned _collection_ (not Stream), or write the elements asynchronously to a dedicated cache as they arrive (Guava, Caffeine, ...), that you can then query as you need.

Comment: @JensHoffmann Infinite streams support is not a requirement of my question, but it is instead, just an additional feature that is provided by my proposal `Cache.of()` by chance. Then, I agree with you when you say: “_I think the solution is to either cache the data src and returned collection_” that is your answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/49881327/1140754, “or write the elements asynchronously to a dedicated cache as they arrive” that is what `Cache.of()` does in `getOrAdvance()`.Nevertheless I will add an example of a `CompletableFuture<Stream<String>>` to give more context..

Comment: @JensHoffmann Done. I included an example that I hope it helps to understand the asynchronous nature of the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the only way to detect the end of the `Stream` traversal is through its `iterator()` or `spliterator()`. Thus, maybe a better option to get a replayable `Stream` is to record its items from its iterator (done by [`Recorder`](https://github.com/javasync/streamemo/blob/master/src/main/java/org/javasync/streams/Replayer.java#L55) class of the example bellow) and then implement a new `Spliterator` that reads the items previously recorded (done by `cacheIterator()`). In this solution I made the [`getOrAdvance()`](https://github.com/javasync/streamemo/blob/master/src/main/java/org/javasync/streams/Replayer.java#L81) method of [`Recorder`](https://github.com/javasync/streamemo/blob/master/src/main/java/org/javasync/streams/Replayer.java#L55) `synchronized` to guarantee that just one resulting stream will get a new item from the source.

So, `Cache.of(dataSrc)` creates a chain of:

`dataSrc` `---->` `Recorder` `---->` `cacheIterator()` `---->` `Stream`

**Side notes**:

1. The resulting stream from the method `Cache.of()` permits limited parallelism. For better splitting support the `cacheIterator()` bellow should return a `Spliterator` implementation instead, such as `AbstractList.RandomAccessSpliterator`.
2. Although it is not a requirement, the `Recorder`/ `cacheIterator()` solution also works with infinite data sources that can be short-circuited later.

E.g. it can cache the items of the infinite stream `nrs` and prints the output bellow without, or with cache (i.e. `nrsReplay`):

```
Random rnd = new Random();
Supplier<Stream<String>> nrs = () -> Stream.generate(() -> rnd.nextInt(99)).map(Object::toString);
IntStream.range(1, 6).forEach(size -> out.println(nrs.get().limit(size).collect(joining(","))));
System.out.println();
Supplier<Stream<String>> nrsReplay = Cache.of(nrs);
IntStream.range(1, 6).forEach(size -> out.println(nrsReplay.get().limit(size).collect(joining(","))));
```

Output:

> 32
>   65,94
>   94,19,34
>   72,77,66,18
>   88,41,34,97,28
>
> 93
>   93,65
>   93,65,71
>   93,65,71,40
>   93,65,71,40,68

```
class Cache {

    public static <T> Supplier<Stream<T>> of(Supplier<Stream<T>> dataSrc) {
        final Spliterator<T> src = dataSrc.get().spliterator(); // !!!maybe it should be lazy and memorized!!!
        final Recorder<T> rec = new Recorder<>(src);
        return () -> {
            // CacheIterator starts on index 0 and reads data from src or
            // from an internal cache of Recorder.
            Spliterator<T> iter = rec.cacheIterator();
            return StreamSupport.stream(iter, false);
        };
    }

    static class Recorder<T> {
        final Spliterator<T> src;
        final List<T> cache = new ArrayList<>();
        final long estimateSize;
        boolean hasNext = true;

        public Recorder(Spliterator<T> src) {
            this.src = src;
            this.estimateSize = src.estimateSize();
        }

        public synchronized boolean getOrAdvance(
                final int index,
                Consumer<? super T> cons) {
            if (index < cache.size()) {
                // If it is in cache then just get if from the corresponding index.
                cons.accept(cache.get(index));
                return true;
            } else if (hasNext)
                // If not in cache then advance the src iterator
                hasNext = src.tryAdvance(item -> {
                    cache.add(item);
                    cons.accept(item);
                });
            return hasNext;
        }

        public Spliterator<T> cacheIterator() {
            return new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<T>(
                    estimateSize, src.characteristics()
            ) {
                int index = 0;
                public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> cons) {
                    return getOrAdvance(index++, cons);
                }
                public Comparator<? super T> getComparator() {
                    return src.getComparator();
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are initializing each `CacheIterator` with `src.estimateSize()`, but after the first traversal, the source may return a decremented value, only reporting the remaining elements, which is a wrong estimate and even worse, would break the contract if the source has the `SIZED` characteristic. Further, you are repeating the `index < cache.size() || hasNext` condition in the `return` statement of `getOrAdvance`, but there, the `index` has already been incremented, so this could wrongly eveluate to `false` and if a previous iteration did already turn `hasNext` to `false`, the result is wrong.

Comment: @Holger Thanks. I will make those fixes this afternoon and then I will update this answer.

Comment: And you need to add `public Comparator<? super T> getComparator() { return rec.src.getComparator(); }` to your `CacheIterator`, otherwise, you’ll get an `IllegalStateException` if the source is `SORTED`. Another problem is that the action passed to `src.tryAdvance` will add an element to `cache` but not increment `index`, so `index < cache.size()` may become `true` again and report the same element again in the next call. This isn’t even possible to fix there, as the right `index` variable is a member of `CacheIterator`, the local variable of `getOrAdvance` is just a copy.

Comment: As a test case, use `Supplier<Stream<Integer>> s = Cache.of(() -> IntStream.range(0, 10).boxed());` and then either `s.get().findFirst(); s.get().toArray();` or `s.get().filter(i -> i<5).forEach(x -> {}); s.get().toArray();`, both variants highlight different aspects of the problems, but not all. But the rabbit hole goes deeper. `estimateSize()` is not required to reflect changes made by an ongoing traversal, so once you have retrieved the first element, subsequent uses would have to clear the `SIZED` property (unless *all* elements have been cached as then, you can use just `cache.size()`).

Comment: @Holger First of all thanks your help. I fixed: 1) the `estimateSize` to report the right value of items; 2) add the missing `getComparator()`; 3) wrong condition on `index < cache.size()`; 4) validation with new unit tests including the test case that you proposed. Furthermore, I add a fast-path on the `Supplier` returned by `Cache.of()` to check whether the `Recorder` has finished saving items and in that case just return the stream from the cached `List`, avoiding the creation of the `CacheIterator`, which in turn would incur in the overhead of the synchronized `getOrAdvance()`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could insert `if(!hasNext) return cache.spliterator();` at the beginning of `cacheIterator()`. Then you don’t need the special case at the caller’s side (i.e. the supplier) and may also remove the `finished()` method. The implementation of the `cache.stream()` method is not different to `StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(), false)`…

Comment: Ok, I will make that improvement. I had no idea that "cache.stream() method is not different to StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(), false)".

Comment: @Holger I am not sure if the `hasNext` field should be `volatile`, or not. I think it should, but I am not sure. We want to avoid that `cache.add()` is reordered with the `hasNext` assignment, thus we should made `hasNext` volatile.

Comment: @Holger Sorry if I am confusing, but inside `getOrAdvance()` instructions can be reordered. Can’t they?  So, when we are reading `hasNext` on `if(!hasNext) // Fast-path when all items…` any previous write such as `cache.add()` can pass over `hasNext = ` assignment and in that case we can get a `stream()` from cache with a wrong estimate size. This is not a possible scenario?

Comment: You are right, there’s the critical access to `cache` if `hasNext` is `true`. So you may use `if(!hasNext) synchronized(this) {return cache.spliterator(); }` to avoid unnecessary costs (`hasNext` may get accessed far more times than a spliterator is created). But I just noticed another problem. The fast path will produce a stream that is `ORDERED` but not `SORTED` nor `DISTINCT`, which may differ significantly from the original stream’s characteristics.

Comment: Regarding the missing `SORTED` or `DISTINCT` characteristics on `spliterator()` from `List cache` it would be better to have a new `Spliterator` implementation with same `src` characteristics and a `tryAdvance` implementation that tracks the array of `List cache`?

Comment: The biggest advantage of the `Spliterator` returned by the `List` is not the footprint of `tryAdvance`, but the fact that it has much better splitting support than the implementation inherited from `AbstractSpliterator` and the always-known size, which yield a much better parallel support (also `toArray` and starting with Java 9, `count()` would benefit). If you don’t need this, you don’t need the fast path. If you want a spliterator supporting the original characteristics and splitting support, use the random access nature of the list and implement `trySplit` using `subList` or index ranges.

Comment: If you have a Java 9 installation, look at the source code of `AbstractList.RandomAccessSpliterator`, then you know what I mean.

Comment: Ok I saw the `AbstractList.RandomAccessSpliterator` and I understood your point about better splitting support. Sleeping on this, I think that for a StackOverflow answer it is enough to: 1) remove the fast-path since it is not complete. 2) add a claim to `Cache.of()` proposal that the resulting stream permits limited parallelism. For better splitting support the `cacheIterator()` should return a `Spliterator` implementation, such as ` AbstractList.RandomAccessSpliterator`.

Comment: Indeed, the fast-path is already beyond the original scope of the question. Showing a correct working solution and hinting about the optimization potential is already enough.

Comment: @Holger Done. Thanks

Comment: @Holger I updated my question with a usage example to highlight the need of a cache and why collecting has some disadvantage. Although, collecting would be an option. I hope it helps to give more context.

Comment: @Holger I remembered that the requirements of original post are inspired in `cache()` method of `Flux` (the reactor implementation of `Publisher` reactive stream). Since `Flux` provides a factory method from `Supplier<Stream<T>>` it would not be a good option to convert it into a `Flux<T>` and use its operations instead of the `Stream<T>`operations? I posted this alternative in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49976529/1140754. What do you think?

Comment: Sure, if you don’t have the requirement to pass a `Stream` to existing code, using an API built to support such use case right from the start makes much more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Guava's [Suppliers#memoize](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.html#memoize-com.google.common.base.Supplier-) function to turn a given Supplier into a caching ("memoizing") one.

1. Turn your dataSrc `Supplier<Stream<T>>` into a `Supplier<List<T>>` that collects the stream
2. Wrap it with [Suppliers#memoize](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.html#memoize-com.google.common.base.Supplier-)

This would be your `cache()` method:

```
private static <T> Supplier<Stream<T>> cache(Supplier<Stream<T>> dataSrc) {
  Supplier<List<T>> memoized = Suppliers.memoize(() -> dataSrc.get().collect(toList()));
  return () -> memoized.get().stream();
}
```

(when mixing in Guava you might need to switch between Guava's version of [c.g.c.b.Supplier](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Supplier.html), and [java.util.Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html), and they can easily be transformed back and forth, however in this case it's not even necessary)

**Example**

Assume a simple Integer stream that returns the first 5 natural numbers and reports computation to stdout:

```
private static Supplier<Stream<Integer>> getDataSrc() {
    return () -> IntStream.generate(new IntSupplier() {
        private int i = 0;

        @Override
        public int getAsInt() {
            System.out.println("Computing next i: " + (i + 1));
            return i += 1;
        }
    }).limit(5).boxed();
}
```

Then running the non-memoized version

```
Supplier<Stream<Integer>> dataSrc = getDataSrc();
System.out.println(dataSrc.get().collect(toList()));
System.out.println(dataSrc.get().collect(toList()));
```

yields

> Computing next i: 1
>   Computing next i: 2
>   Computing next i: 3
>   Computing next i: 4
>   Computing next i: 5
>   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>   Computing next i: 1
>   Computing next i: 2
>   Computing next i: 3
>   Computing next i: 4
>   Computing next i: 5
>   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

And running the memoized version

```
Supplier<Stream<Integer>> dataSrc = cached(getDataSrc());
System.out.println(dataSrc.get().collect(toList()));
System.out.println(dataSrc.get().collect(toList()));
```

yields

> Computing next i: 1
>   Computing next i: 2
>   Computing next i: 3
>   Computing next i: 4
>   Computing next i: 5
>   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: Regarding the requirements stated in my question, I think your proposal breaks the following goal: "_avoid the additional traversal to collect items_".

Comment: This one caches the source though. One traversal when accessed the first time, then traversing the cached result. I don't see how it breaks the stated requirement?

Comment: On the first traversal of your example `System.out.println(dataSrc.get().collect(toList()));` there are in fact 2 traversals. One from the `Suppliers.memoize(() -> dataSrc.get().collect(toList()))` and another from the `System.out.println(dataSrc.get().collect(toList()));`.

Comment: I understand but I think you're conflating two requirements. You mentioned in the comments that you want to cache the source because getting the stream might be expensive (network). This one does, as does the "manual" solution by collecting explicitly and re-using the returned List. Avoiding the traversal might not make much of a difference (iterating n or n+1 times over data that is held in memory might not make a difference if *fetching* dominates)

Comment: If you are working on infinite data sources, which can be short-circuited later, then you cannot cache it before-hand. In this case you have to cache it on demand. Nevertheless, you are right that this question does not impose any requirement on infinite data sources.

Comment: OK, makes sense.

Comment: @MiguelGamboa any caching solution adds a limitation on processing of infinite stream which doesn’t exist when processing the original non-caching stream.

Comment: @Holger Indeed. So, in this case, what would be your recommendation?

Comment: @MiguelGamboa I don’t think that there is a solution. Caching only has a point if the data is limited to a reasonably small fraction of the available memory.

Comment: @Holger the question doesn’t state anything about infinite streams requirement. That was just an additional feature that was supported in one of my proposals. So, assuming that we have limited data from the source, what would be your option? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If using the [Reactor Project](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core) is an option, then you can simply convert the `Supplier<Stream<T>>` to a `Flux<T>`, which already provides the utility `cache()` method and henceforward use `Flux<T>` operations rather than  `Stream<T>` operations.

Regarding the example of the original post, where `temps` is a `CompletableFuture<Stream<Integer>>` with the result of an HTTP request transformed in a sequence of temperatures in Celsius, then we can perform both queries in the following way:

```
Flux<Integer> cache = Flux.fromStream(temps::join).cache();
cache.distinct().count().subscribe(out::println);
cache.reduce(Integer::max).subscribe(out::println);
```

This solution **avoids**: 1) `IllegalStateException` on further traversals of this sequence; 2) a first traversal to collect items in a cache.